# Running an action after editing a bot's comment?

Tags: github, github-actions

I need to run an action every time a specific comment (one made by [another action](https://github.com/apps/github-actions)) is edited.

So far it looks like it is only possible to run an action when the **MAIN** comment on the PR is edited, not when any other comment (even by another author) is edited.

The workflow looks like this:

1. When needed a label is added to a specific PR manually
2. Comment bot via Github Action runs and makes an automatic comment on the PR
3. The above comment must be edited manually by the PR approver BEFORE approving the PR
4. **THIS** action I am trying to make is supposed to run when step 3 comment is edited, it will parse the comment and dump the manually edited info into a metadata.json file.

This is an example of the bot comment which, once edited would run the parsing action I am working on:

[image: bot comment to be edited]

The problem is, I cannot see any way to have an action trigger when the ˆˆabove comment is editedˆˆ

I've got the action set out as follows:

```
name: Parse comment
on:
  pull_request:
      types: [edited]
```

The action works fine though when the main comment is edited, but that is *not* the comment I wish to parse.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to do this with the following. Basically get the bot comment ID with another action, then act on the output of that step.

```
name: Parse comment
on:
  pull_request:
      types: [edited]
jobs:
  parse_comment:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - uses: peter-evans/find-comment@v1
        id: bot
        with:
          issue-number: ${{ github.event.number }}
          body-includes: "<!-- GH BOT -->"

      - name: Print Comment ID & Author
        run: |
          echo ${{ steps.bot.outputs.comment-id }}
          echo ${{ steps.bot.outputs.comment-author }}

      - uses: actions-ecosystem/action-regex-match@v2
        id: description
        with:
          text: ${{ steps.bot.outputs.comment-body }}
          regex: '^[A-Za-z_"]+:\s+.*$'
          flags: m
```

"bot" is the name of the the step, and 'comment-body' is an argument that the action holds for the value of the body, even after it is edited. So `steps.bot.outputs.comment-body` has the value of the bot's comment. It is this that I used to run my regex on with another action.

I also have the author and comment id echoed for brevity in case it changes in the future.